# How to save the played movie time so that next time the user can play it from where they paused?

Tags: iphone

I just want to know that how can I save the time of a played movie so that again, when the user play it, they play from the paused time and not from the beginning.

Second, I want to know which media player is better for me for this kind of application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I recommend that you use the **MPMoviePlayerController** to play the movies.  That will make this simple.  **MPMoviePlayerController** implements the **MPMediaPlayback** protocol, which includes a read/write property named **currentPlaybackTime**.

You can read the time from **currentPlaybackTime** when the user stops or pauses the movie and save that value. Later, when the user wants to continue watching from that same point, you simply set **currentPlaybackTime** to that saved value.